# Custom remove cart item functionality in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I have the add item function set-up, which looks like this:

```
                <div class="col s4">
                    <a class="addtocart_link" href="<?php echo esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->add_to_cart_text() ); ?>">
                        <span class="action_box fa fa-plus"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
```

Is there a similar or another way to create the remove item function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes there is `wc_get_cart_remove_url` but you need to get the cart item key to do so you can use the following :

```
<?php
$cart_item_key = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product->get_ID() );
$in_cart       = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $cart_item_key );
if ( $in_cart ) {
    $cart_item_remove_url = wc_get_cart_remove_url( $cart_item_key );
    ?>
    <div class="col s4">
        <a class="remove_from_cart" href="<?php echo esc_url( $cart_item_remove_url ); ?>" title="remove_from_cart ">
            <span class=" action_box fa fa-minus "></span></a>
            </div>
    <?php

}
```

Of course the  code above will work for simple product only and simply it will remove all items from the carts.

**If you want to reduce the cart item one item at time you need to use different approach as follow:**

**First :** Let add our Remove link & add_to_cart with some attribute like quantity and product id in order to process the data with our script.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'remove_product' );

function remove_product() {
    global $product;

    $cart_item_key        = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product->get_ID() );
    $in_cart              = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $cart_item_key );
    $cart_item_remove_url = wc_get_cart_remove_url( $cart_item_key );

?>

<div class="col s4">
<a class="addtocart_link"
id ="add_to_cart" 
title="add_to_cart" 
data-product-id="<?php echo $product->get_ID(); ?>"
data-cart-item-key="<?php echo $cart_item_key; ?>">
<span class="action_box fa fa-plus"></span></a>
            </div>
<?php
    if ( $in_cart ) {
        $quantities = WC()->cart->get_cart_item_quantities();
        foreach ( $quantities as $key => $quantity ) {
            if ( $product->get_ID() == $key ) {
                if ( $quantity > 1 ) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="col s4">
                    <a id="remove_one_item" class="remove_from_cart" href="#" 
                    data-product-id="<?php echo $product->get_ID(); ?>"
                    data-in-cart-qty="<?php echo  $quantity; ?>"
                    data-cart-item-key="<?php echo $cart_item_key; ?>"
                    title="remove_from_cart ">
                        <span class=" action_box fa fa-minus "></span></a>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
        <div class="col s4">
        <a class="remove_from_cart" href="<?php echo esc_url( $cart_item_remove_url ); ?>" title="remove_from_cart ">
        <span class=" action_box fa fa-minus "></span></a>

        <?php
    }

}
```

**Now Let we need add our script to Wordpress Footer or you can added it to your Javascript file**

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'change_qty_script' );

function change_qty_script() {
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#remove_one_item').click(function () {

        var current_qty = parseInt($(this).attr('data-in-cart-qty'));
        var id = $(this).attr('data-product-id');
        var cat_item_key = $(this).attr('data-cart-item-key');
        var data = {
            product_id: id,
            quantity: current_qty - 1,
            cat_item_key : cat_item_key
        };
        var url = wc_add_to_cart_params.wc_ajax_url.toString().replace('%%endpoint%%', 'update_qty');
        $.post(url, data, function (response) {
            if (!response) {
                return;
            }
            if (response) {
                location.reload();
            }
        });
    });
    $('#add_to_cart').click(function () {

        var id = $(this).attr('data-product-id');
        var cat_item_key = $(this).attr('data-cart-item-key');
        var data = {
            product_id: id,
            quantity: 1,
        };
        var url = wc_add_to_cart_params.wc_ajax_url.toString().replace('%%endpoint%%', 'add_to_cart');
        $.post(url, data, function (response) {
            if (!response) {
                return;
            }
            if (response) {
                location.reload();
            }
        });
    });

    });
    </script>
    <?php

}
```

**Finally we need to process the data when the user clicked remove link**

```
add_action( 'wc_ajax_update_qty', 'update_qty' );

function update_qty() {
    ob_start();
    $product_id   = absint( $_POST['product_id'] );
    $product      = wc_get_product( $product_id );
    $quantity     = $_POST['quantity'];
    $cat_item_key = $_POST['cat_item_key'];

    WC()->cart->set_quantity( $cat_item_key, $quantity, true );

    wp_send_json( 'done' );
}
```

Place the codes above in your `functions.php` and you are good to go.

all codes above has bees tested and it's working fine.

Comment: It works fine, thanks! But if there's a product with the quantity of let's say 5 in the shopping cart it removes all 5 not only 1.

Comment: @LukasHillebrand  today I left my office I will  figure it out tomorrow am sure it’s possible

Comment: Super! let me buy you a beer / coffee for the help :-)

Comment: @LukasHillebrand sure it will be pleasure :), i start working on this request i have one question you are displaying those two button in the archive pages correct?

Comment: On the product single page: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fxjrclcem3baefn/Screenshot%202018-09-14%2014.25.34.png?dl=0

Comment: Thank you very much! still isn't working for me: the "-" doesn't appear and I have no errors in the console.

Comment: @LukasHillebrand can you post the web link to check it why as i have tested this code above locally and it's working fine

Comment: Sure, but I need to send it in private to you! Where?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180102/discussion-between-kashalo-and-lukas-hillebrand).